# Future value of loan: interest calculated daily and compounded at end of each calendar month

Tags: mortgage, calculation

Future value of a loan: Interest calculated daily on a 365 day basis. Interest is compounded monthly. Fixed interest rate. Fixed term.

Is there a way to calculate what the loan balance will be in 1 years time using a formula. Instead of working through 12 months loan calculations on individual excel rows.

[image: Spreadsheet calculations]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula

[image: equation]

where `s` is the principal, `i` is the rate, and `dk` is the number of days in month k

demonstrated here using Mathematica.

```
d[1]=  9; d[2]= 31; d[3]= 30; d[4]=31; d[5]= 31;
d[6]= 28; d[7]= 31; d[8]= 30; d[9]=31; d[10]=30;
d[11]=31; d[12]=31; d[13]=30;

t[n_] := s Product[1/365 (365 + i*d[k]), {k, n}]

s=50000;
i=0.055;

t[13]
```

> ```
> 52892.
> ```

Or in Excel.  Ironically this only seems to work in Excel 365.

```
=C1*PRODUCT(1/365*(365+C2*A1:INDEX(A:A,B1)))
```

[image]

***Longhand version***

```
s = 50000
i = 0.055

s/365^13*(365 + 9 i)*(365 + 31 i)*(365 + 30 i)*
  (365 + 31 i)*(365 + 31 i)*(365 + 28 i)*
  (365 + 31 i)*(365 + 30 i)*(365 + 31 i)*
  (365 + 30 i)*(365 + 31 i)*(365 + 31 i)*(365 + 30 i) = 52892.02
```

Comment: Im sure that this response will be useful to the OP.  I would like to add that there are also some "built-in" financial functions in Excel for doing this sort of thing.  The "FV" function (i.e. = FV(....)) may be particularly useful for him/her, and they might also refer to other financial functions such as =PPMT(...), =IPMT(...), etc.

Comment: @Paul - I don't know of an inbuild Excel finance function that uses the 365 day basis.