# Remaining Balance Formula for Actual/360 and Actual/Actual Accrual Methods

Tags: loans, amortization, accrual

Is there a concise formula for calculating the remaining balance of a loan with actual/360 and actual/actual accruals?

I know for 30/360 amortizations, the remaining balance is just the FV of the principle less the FV of the loan payment annuity.

// Remaining balance for a loan amount of "princ"
// and a monthly payment of "coupon" using a 30/360 accrual

Remaining Balance = princ * (1+r)^n - coupon * [((1+r)^n - 1) / r]
I know with actuals, we can't easily use the annuity formula, since we don't have level payments.

I was hoping there was a formula that can take into account these "errors", where the annuity assumes 30 day, missing the day in 31, compound the error at the same rate, allowing us to still calculate the accurate remaining balance.

Or do we have to build a full amortization schedule to compute?

For a refresher on accrual methods, [here is a terrific blog post explaining the differences](https://propertymetrics.com/blog/30-360-vs-actual-360-vs-actual-365/)

Thank you!

Comment: You haven't posted the blog link.

Comment: If the interest payment is  (outstanding balance)*(days e.g. 31)*(annual rate)/360, how is the payment to principal calculated?  Or are the monthly payments all the same, with the portion of payment to principal varying in complement to the interest payment?

Comment: @ChrisDegnen I added blog link. You got it - the monthly stays the same, but the interest amount varies month to month (rate / 28, rate / 30, rate / 31) and therefore the principle amount changes too. All accrual methods feature a fixed monthly payment and all must amortize to zero by loan end. But they have different principle amortization curves to get there.

Answer (score 1):

The following formula will give the balance `b` in month `n`

[image: eqn]

where

```
s is the loan principal
d is the periodic payment
x[k] is the periodic rate in month k
```

For example.  First calculating some values for a 10% 30/360 case, where

```
r is the 30/360 periodic rate
m is the number of periods

s = 1000
r = 0.1*30/360
m = 12

d = r s/(1 - (1 + r)^-m) = 87.9159
```

The balance in month `n` is given by

```
b = (d + (1 + r)^n (r s - d))/r
```

or the first formula can be used, with

```
x[1] = r
x[2] = r
...
x[12] = r
```

In both cases with `n` = 12 the balance `b` is zero.

Now using varying rates according to actual/360:

```
x[1] = 0.1*31/360
x[2] = 0.1*28/360
...
x[12] = 0.1*31/360
```

With `n` = 12 the balance `b` is no longer zero, as expected.

```
b = 0.568906
```

Setting `b` equal to zero and solving numerically for `d` yields

```
d = 87.9611
```

So for example, the actual/360 balance in month 7 can be found

```
n = 7
b = 428.809
```

Checking with an Excel amortization

[image]

There is an example of using a product function in Excel [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/131316/11768).

Comment: Thank you @ChrisDegnan for the answer. I was hoping for a formula that didn't involve a loop, since it doesn't scale well - but yours is the correct answer by loop. Unfortunately for my effort, I think a loop may be the only way.

Comment: Do you mean a loop to solve for the payment amount `d`?  That reminds me to add an Excel solver [example](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/50398/11768).  Perhaps you mean a loop for the products and summation.  If you put it together in Excel I hope you will add a screenshot to your post.

Comment: Just the opposite - I know how to solve via loop, I'm looking for a non-loop. Something akin to the FV of the series of payments + error between 30 and ACT. The excel version is a loop - even without solver, it is still iteratively going through each period.

Comment: The FV summation with a constant interest term and payment amount can be expressed in a closed form by induction, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1039786/119821).  When the interest term or payment amount varies the closed form cannot be obtained in this way.